# Invalid src prop in Nextjs Image tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
<Image
  src={"http://localhost:3000/images/img.jpeg"}
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="cover"
  width={"100%"}
  height={"100%"}
/>
```

The error is :

[image]

How do I solve ?

Comment: Did you try visiting the link inside the error that your image is showing? It contains the solution

Comment: images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
Insert this to your next config in module.exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that, the `url` that you are using for the `Image` is not from a `trusted hostname(domain)`.
You just need to add that `hostname or domain` inside your `next.config.js` file.
Follow the following steps :

1. Create a next.config.js file inside your root directory.
2. Add the following code inside your next.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.example.com'],
  },
}
```

This must solve your problem.
For more `details` you can `read` more on this page :
[next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction)